# How can I add a search button in plotly modebar?

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a search button available to add in plotly modebar ? It has to search for `x` vector values.

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)

fig
    fig%>%
      config(modeBarButtonsToAdd = list("addsearchbutton"))
```

Comment: could you expand on what the "search button" should do? Your plot looks like a scatter plot of Petal.Length vs Sepal.Length. What do you want the user to search for?

Comment: I edited to make it clear